# Can you select the Nth row in the dataset returned by SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, select

In pseudo-code, what I mean is, can you do something like this (similar to TOP):

```
SELECT Row 2
*
FROM Table
WHERE Column1 = Condition
```

I wanted to do something for testing - I can't think of a real world scenario for this. Just curious if it's possible. I can't find anything on the Interwebz about it.

Comment: A real world scenario for this is called "paging".

Comment: You will get many answers on how to perform paging, and some will perform ok for the first few pages but deteriorate quickly as you "page" down. Please read http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/66030/ and the follow-on comments http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic672980-329-1.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand: is there a better solution for "random access" paging?

Comment: @Quassnoi I'm not sure I understand what "random access" paging means? Do you mean where you click on page 42 and you get page 42? I think there are some pretty clever solutions in the comments link I provided, yes.

Comment: @AaronBertrand who says this has anything to do with paging? I often have to do this with rows that are identical other than a datestamp and need to get a certain row i.e. 3rd day or 4th day etc

Comment: @Gratzy I'm just going along with the theme that Quassnoi started. Whether it is finding the Nth row or the Nth page of M rows I'd still call that paging (just one row per page instead of M).

Comment: Yah, how'd this turn into a paging thread? Hehe.

Comment: @Yatrix they're just comments based on a pretty sensible conclusion from your question. If you don't think they're relevant you can ignore them. Other readers might find this question because they were looking for paging and also didn't know what it was commonly called.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Whatever you say, man. I got what I was looking for. Use and abuse the comments all you guys want. Just try to keep noise down so the neighbors don't complain.

Comment: Question got down-voted? To each his own, I suppose. Suggestions are always appreciated if the question wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) rn
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   col1 = condition
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

This would give you the 9th row:

```
select top 1 *
from (
    select top 9 *
    from MyTable
    order by 1) as x
order by 1 desc
```

Comment: This is better solution as this will work in DB where rownumber is not supported

Comment: @ejb_guy But I specified one that supports it in my tags. =)

Comment: @Yatrix Yeap. Agreed. SO is now-a-days top link in google. If somebody is looking for simmilar problem but in DB where rownum is not supported than this will come handy :-)

Comment: @ejb_guy: this is a nice solution for those poor souls still stuck with `SQL Server 2000`, but it will have to sort twice. Not sure why would someone want to use it in `2005` and above.

Comment: @Quassnoi to be fair, the other solutions on the page sort once, but could return the results in any arbitrary order - unless you add a second sort on the outer query.

Comment: @Quassnoi he said it was for testing. So I like to go with simple over performance when just playing with it in development or testing.

Comment: @JBrooks sure, but when someone tests it and it performs ok in their dev environment where they have 500 rows, don't you think it's fair to warn them that the cost of those two sorts will increase dramatically on real tables?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I don't think you would ever want the 9th or 4th row in production.  But if you did this will sort all of the rows first (probably on a column with an index), and then just sort 9 on the second step.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: the query will return exactly one record, in any arbirary order. But if there were a `rn BETWEEN` in the query, and you  appended the `ORDER BY` to the end, it would be a no-op: `SQL Server` would not sort the resultset again because it had been already sorted (or taken out of the index) by the `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause.

Comment: Who knew my stupid question would inspire so much conversation. +1 to me. Hehe.

Comment: @Quassnoi in the case where more than one row is returned (sorry, was still on the "paging" mindset), are you 100% certain that behavior is always guaranteed? I don't believe it is a fact that a query against a CTE with an inner OVER() clause will sort by the ORDER BY in that OVER() clause. And even if it is, what if the desired sort is not the same as the OVER() clause (e.g. a top 10 list)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: nothing is guaranteed with the optimizer, but with the current implementation the resultset returned from `CTE` would be marked as sorted (`ROW_NUMBER()` is not even parallelizable), so the next relops would not sorted is again. Also, `SQL Server` optimizes `ROW_NUMBER() < @n` to use `TOP`. If the desired order is not the same as the `OVER` order (say you need a TOP 10 users ordered by last name), then of course it would have to sort twice (and the author's query would have to add another `ORDER BY` and sort thrice)

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH QUERY AS (
               SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column1) AS RowNumber
               FROM Table
               )
SELECT * FROM QUERY WHERE ROWNUMBER = N
```